# Console application tries to find database in path of local machine

Tags: c#

I created a console application in C# which works fine in my machine. But when it is installed in other machine, it fails with error message stating that the database file is not present. 
Also, it tries to find the database in the path of local machine where development was done. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Please show your connection string. Does machines in one network?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've hardcoded the path for the database file in the program. You could try putting both of them in the same directory and then declaring a variable:

```
var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "\\fileName.txt");
```

and then reference that variable as the path for the database file.